# cannot Solve BufferOverflow Exception - Java

Tags: java, networking, udp, bytebuffer

Below sender/receiver code attempts to transfer the image file (49692 bytes) from client to server (Uses UDP socket).Although the size of the bytearray is exactly equal to the bytebuffer, i was thrown the exception (mentioned in line no,30 in receiver side). Any help?

Sender Side:

```
public class P_Sender
{
  public static DatagramSocket sock =null;
  public static DatagramPacket sendPacket,recvPacket=null;
  public static int port=15000;
  public static InetAddress ip;
  public static ByteBuffer fileBuffer;
  public static byte[] sendBytes;   

  public static byte[] int2Byte(int i) throws IOException
   {
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(Integer.SIZE/4);
     DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(baos);
     dos.writeInt(i);
     byte[] result=baos.toByteArray();
     dos.close();    
     return result;
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
      FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream("abc.jpeg").getChannel();
      fileBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) inChannel.size());
      inChannel.read(fileBuffer);
      inChannel.close();
      fileBuffer.flip();
      ip=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      sock=new DatagramSocket();
      sendBytes=new byte[fileBuffer.capacity()];
      System.out.println("Length:" +fileBuffer.capacity());
      fileBuffer.get(sendBytes);
      sendPacket=new DatagramPacket(sendBytes,sendBytes.length,ip,port);
      sock.send(sendPacket);
      System.out.println("sent Packet Length:" +sendPacket.getLength());
    }

}
```

Receiver Side:

```
 public class P_Recv 
{
    public static DatagramSocket sock;
    public static DatagramPacket recvDataPacket;
    public static byte[] recvBytes;
    public static int port;
    byte[] dataBuf;
    public static InetAddress ip;
    public static ByteBuffer fileBuffer;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
      SrReceiver srobj=new SrReceiver();
      sock=new DatagramSocket(15000);
      recvBytes=new byte[49692];
      recvDataPacket=new DatagramPacket(recvBytes,recvBytes.length);
      sock.receive(recvDataPacket);
      System.out.println("Received Packet Length: "+recvDataPacket.getLength());
      fileBuffer= ByteBuffer.allocate(recvDataPacket.getLength());
      System.out.println(fileBuffer.capacity());
      fileBuffer.clear();
      fileBuffer.flip();
      fileBuffer.put(recvBytes);//Here i am thrown BufferOverflowException
      FileChannel outchannel = new FileOutputStream(new File("abcd.jpeg")).getChannel();
      outchannel.write(fileBuffer);
      outchannel.close();
      sock.close();
    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: `Integer.SIZE/4`?

Comment: Are you sure the recvDataPacket is that size? You don't check it and use that to allocate the buffer, then write more.

Comment: I checked it in the sender's side and hence hard coded it. i am pretty sure that 49692 has been transferred to receiver's side (I could print that as well).

Comment: Try using rewind or position(0).I am not sure flip is doing what you think is doing. If it works let me know. I will put as answer

Comment: I checked that the position of the buffer is zero.

Comment: flip also sets the limit which is the current position

Comment: tried rewind() and position(0) as well. Not successful.

Comment: What is SrReceiver? Let me check some code where I use byte buffers and handle these exceptions constantly

Comment: disregard that. I took that line out.Sorry about that.

Comment: the only thing different is that I use mark to reposition the buffer after the exception. It seems somewhere else

Comment: I temporarily solved it using file stream but i need solution for the above as i have to do some operations with byte buffer. Posting the working code as answer  would still be helpful for me.

Comment: I would look at this later. Busy now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `flip()` to after the `put()`. It is only used before `write()` or any flavour of `get()`. It is not used before `read()` or any flavour of `put()`.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `clear()`. A brand new buffer is already clear.

Comment: Not unless you put it back before the write.